# Unlock shared content blocks in Sitefinity API

Tags: sitefinity

I want to unlock shared content blocks using Sitefinity API, but it does not appear that the ContentItems returned by ContentManager's GetContent() method has any attribute related to locking like the PageManager has (LockedBy). Yet, the Sitefinity UI clearly shows content blocks that are locked by users. Is there a method I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there is a **Temp** version for your content item and if so, then it means it is locked. You can get the locked By userId from the **LastModifiedBy** property of the Temp version.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick. For reference, I'm querying the content block manager to get master content, then trying to get the temp version. If that is not null, I'm checking it in, publishing the updated master, and saving the changes.